# Orthogonal bases for the eigenspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gram-schmidt

I'm looking at a math problem which I have the solution for.
The question looks like this:

**Question**

By hand, calculate the eigenvectors and find orthogonal bases for the eigenspaces.

The eigenvalues are [eigenvalues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzo1p.png)

**Solution**

[Image of the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb2m5.png)

**My problem**

In the solution it is written *"It is easily checked that v3 is orthogonal to v1 and q2"*

When vectors are orthogonal to each other the inner product should be equal to zero. But  and  is not equal to zero as far as I can see.
What am I missing? Is the solution wrong? (I guess not).

Best Regards
Christian

Comment: The solution is correct overall, but that one sentence isn’t. There’s no particular reason to expect the eigenspaces to be orthogonal since the original matrix is not symmetric. Perhaps that sentence is a cut-and-paste error in the text, left over from the solution to some other problem that was copied and modified for this one.

Comment: In the future, please enter all of the important parts of your question as text instead of posting pictures of the content. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries of the question. You can find a tutorial and quick reference for formatting mathematical expressions with MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Okay thank you for the answer. 
And I will enter all parts of the question in plain text in the future. Thanks for the reference by the way!